# Prevent mqtt.js to disconnect in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, mqtt

### Short

Is there a way of preventing mqtt in the browser to disconnect when the browser loses focus?

### The long one

Previously I used Paho mqtt from a browser talking to a secure web socket.
Paho sometimes had trouble setting up the connection with Paho therefore we changed to mqtt.js

I find it much better at setting up the connection.

But, when I leave the browser for a while it seems to disconnect, however it connects really quick again when the tab gets the focus back.

I can see the reason for having a timeout function, but it should be possible to turn it off.

Is it?

Answer (score 0):

This will be down to the browser suspending the tab when it's not visible to save resources (e.g. battery on mobile devices/laptops) and memory by swapping out the page.

In this case it is unlikely you will be able to influence this from within the page (as this would defeat the point)

Comment: that cannot be correct. I've had the Paho version running for hours without using the browser.  So there must be something in the mqtt.js code that differs.
That is at PC:s

Comment: In that case have you checked the broker logs to see what if any reason is given for the disconnect? I'm still pretty confident it will be down to timing out the keepalive because the page is suspended.